# Can't locate MyPerlModule.pm in @INC

Tags: perl

I am trying use my own .pm in a perl script, it is throwing the following error on Mac OS Big Sur . The same works on mac OS 10.15.7.

```
Can't locate MyPerlModule.pm in @INC 
(@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.30 /Network/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.30 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.30.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.30 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30
)
```

The script already has *use lib* specifying the path to folder containing the MyPerlModule.pm. But this path is not getting appended to @INC.

Also tried BEGIN{push @INC, *path* }but still there is the same error.

Comment: Try reducing your script to the bare minimum: i.e. the two lines 'use lib "/some/path"; use MyPerlModule;' then see what error message you get.

Comment: @DaveMitchell, I see the same error with the bare minimum script too.

Answer (score 3):

If you show your actual program, we may be able to see that you are doing.

In the error message, you see a list of paths that are in `@INC`. I don't see something that looks like a local path that you expect. Something's not working right there.

You mention using `BEGIN { push @INC, ... }`, but normally people want their local library directory to be the first that Perl checks. You can use `unshift` instead:

```
BEGIN { unshift @INC, 'lib' }
```

But, this is the same thing that `lib` does:

```
use lib qw(lib);
```

Either way has to happen before you try to load your module

```
use lib qw(lib);
use MyPerlModule;  # in lib/MyPerlModule.pm
```

Note that some people may be use to putting their local module in the same directory as the script. Before Perl 5.26, `@INC` included the current working directory as an entry. [That doesn't work anymore](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2017/01/v5-26-removes-dot-from-inc/).